# Passing by Reference fails [C Programming]

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the function targetSum to find out if there are two values in the array that match the target value entered by the user. It takes in the array, the target, the 2 indices, and the size of the array. When I try to output the result in the main function, the value of indices does not change (even though I'm passing as reference). Help appreciated! [code below]

```
int targetSum(int arr[], int size, int target, int index1, int index2)
{
    int max, min, sum;

    index1 = 0;
    index2 = size - 1;

    min = arr[index1];
    max = arr[index2];

    while (index1 != index2) {

        sum = max + min;

        if (sum == target) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (sum < target) {
                index1++;
                min = arr[index1];
        }
        else if (sum > target) {
                index2--;
                max = arr[index2];
            }
        }
    return -1;
}
```

---

```
int index1, index2 = 0;
int target;
        if(target == -999){ // the program exits if the user enters target as -999
            printf("Good Bye");
            break;
        }

        if (targetSum(toArr, size, target, &index1, &index2) == 1) {
            printf("Output: Success! Elements at indices ");
            printf("%d", index1);
            printf(" and ");
            printf("%d", index2);
            printf(" add up to ");
            printf("%d", target);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Output: Target sum failed!\n");
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't your compiler give you any warnings?

Comment: your tagetSum function should accept index1 and index2 as pointer type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're passing to the function doesn't match what it's expecting.

The last two parameters to `targetSum` are of type `int` but you're passing in values of type `int *`.  Your compiler should have warned you about this.

Change the function parameters to pointers:

```
int targetSum(int arr[], int size, int target, int *index1, int *index2)
```

Then dereference them as necessary in the body of the function.

Comment: when I try to pass them with the * it doesnt work at all, it then gives an error: indirection requires pointer operand

Comment: @Asher I didn't say to change how you call the function.  I said to change the types of the parameters to match what you're passing in.

Comment: @Asher Then what *exactly* did you change?

Comment: okay so I tried dereferencing index1 and index2. everything works fine but the it keeps printing that it failed (it shouldnt fail).

Comment: @Asher That's because you declared the function to return an `int` but never bothered to return anything`.

Comment: i did add a return 1; in the first if statement in the function..

Comment: @Asher But what happens if you get out of the `while` loop?

Comment: okay my bad, i added a return -1; right after the while loop, i think i missed out on it while posting the question, ill edit that.

Comment: @Asher Copy/paste the code that you tested.  That avoids transcription errors.

Answer (score 0):

In function definition, add pointer operator (*) everywhere before variables index1 and index2